# Delete rows following a duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-delete, gaps-and-islands

I have a list of user login and logout stamps. Unfortunately a LOGIN entry might not always be followed by a LOGOUT entry.
I wish to delete any row which has the same **[event]** and **[user_id]** as previous row when ordered by **[event_date]**
Any suggestions on how to do this?

**Example table**

```
CREATE TABLE #LOG (
    [id] int IDENTITY(1,1),
    [user_id] int,
    [event] varchar(50),
    [event_date] datetime
);
INSERT INTO #LOG ([user_id], [event], [event_date])
SELECT 1,'LOGIN',{ts '2010-12-15 15:31:59'}
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'LOGOUT',{ts '2010-12-15 15:32:55'}
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'LOGIN',{ts '2010-12-15 15:38:04'}
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'LOGOUT',{ts '2010-12-15 15:38:17'}
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'LOGOUT',{ts '2010-12-15 15:38:45'} -- Delete
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'LOGIN',{ts '2010-12-15 16:59:39'}
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'LOGOUT',{ts '2010-12-15 17:00:08'}
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'LOGOUT',{ts '2010-12-15 17:00:39'} -- Delete
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'LOGOUT',{ts '2010-12-15 17:01:16'} -- Delete
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'LOGIN',{ts '2010-12-15 17:01:38'}
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'LOGIN',{ts '2010-12-15 17:02:26'} -- Delete
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'LOGOUT',{ts '2010-12-15 17:02:39'}
```

Comment: +1 for teaching me some new syntax. I have never seen the `{ts 'xxx'}`before.

Comment: What is this {ts 'xxx'}?

Comment: By the looks of it, `{ts 'xxx'}` seems to relate to a timestamp, very interesting!

Comment: It allows the parser to determine the datatype, so as not to confuse it as a string, which may then need implicit conversion to a date.

Comment: Thanks @Dems, where can I find details about this? I would like to read more about it. Any link?

Comment: Start with this?  http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/754

Comment: Aah, the {ts 'xxx'} is ODBC Datetime Format . You can find it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190234%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;WITH T1 AS
(
SELECT * , 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY event_date)-
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [user_id], [event] 
                               ORDER BY event_date) AS Grp
FROM #LOG
),T2 AS
(
SELECT 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [user_id], [event], Grp 
                          ORDER BY event_date) RN
FROM T1
)
DELETE FROM T2 
WHERE RN > 1
```

Comment: +1 : Over a small dataset, without an index, this does appear more effecient than other options.  Which impresses me, I'd expect it wasn't, need to play with how SQL Server optimises ROW_NUMBER() a bit more :)   With a covering index on user_id, event_date, however, the version without ROW_NUMBER() seems more efficient.

Comment: I know a little about CTE. I have also used this in my recursive query. But how deleting from T2 effecting #LOG? What am I missing?

Comment: @Dems - Thanks, I haven't tested performance I'll leave that to the OP against their data. I saw on twitter that SQL Server 2011 will support `lag` and increase support for windowed functions generally which I think should make this type of query easier. @Muhammad deleting from a CTE acts the same as deleting from a View. It deletes the corresponding row in the base table.

Comment: @Muhammad : Imagine the CTE as a View with Schema Binding.  By deleteing from the view, you are deleting from the underlying tables.

Comment: @Martin : Expanding the windowed function support will be good.  I can start eating into my colleagues claims that SAS can do statistical work that SQL Sever sucks at :)

Comment: @Dems - Adam Machanic tweeted [this slide](http://a.yfrog.com/img616/1917/k7clc.jpg) from an Itzik presentation on what (apparently) is to be expected in the next Denali CTP

Comment: @Martin: Most all solutions worked perfectly. This solution did however also teach me to use multiple CTE's. Thanks for the help all!

Comment: @Martin - Itzik has been holding a torch for those features for years and he is right, they are needed.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that you want to delete entries such that the pattern is always `In,Out,In,Out,etc`.

This means a record is deleted if the preceding record (when order by user_id, then event_date), is of the same event.

There are two options I'd use to go about this...

```
DELETE
  #log
WHERE
  event = (
           SELECT
             TOP 1
             event
           FROM
             #log AS [preceding]
           WHERE
             [preceding].user_id = #log.user_id
             AND [preceding].event_date < #log.event_date
           ORDER BY
             [preceding].event_date DESC
          )
```

Or...

```
WITH ordered_log AS (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY event_date) AS user_event_id,
    *
  FROM
    #log
)

DELETE
  ordered_log
FROM
  ordered_log
INNER JOIN
  ordered_log   AS [preceding]
    ON  [preceding].login_id      = [ordered_log].login_id
    AND [preceding].user_event_id = [ordered_log].user_event_id - 1
WHERE
  [preceding].event = [ordered_log].event
```

Either way, I highly recommend an Index covering `user_id` then `event_date`.

**Note:** The first version does not cope with the possibility of two events having the same timestamp.  The latter, however, does.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) functionality of SQL Server would be an option

**SQL Statement**

```
;WITH q AS (
    SELECT  Rownumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY user_id, event_date)
    , user_id
    , event
    , event_date
    FROM    #LOG
)
DELETE FROM #LOG
FROM    #LOG l
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  q2.*
            FROM    q q1
                    INNER JOIN q q2 ON  q2.Rownumber = q1.Rownumber + 1
                                        AND q2.user_id = q1.user_id
                                        AND q2.event = q1.event
        ) q ON  q.user_id = l.user_id
                AND q.event_date = l.event_date

SELECT  *
FROM    #LOG
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to delete duplicate row. Then no need to set the order by clause.

Try below

```
Delete l from #LOG l
Inner Join 
(
    Select id from #LOG l
    Inner Join(
        Select user_id, event from #LOG 
        group by user_id, event
        having COUNT(user_id) > 1 and COUNT(event) > 1
    )T
    on (l.user_id = t.user_id) and (l.event = t.event)
)T
on T.id = l.id
```